# replace column value if string does not start with "x"

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df read in with pandas, and in a specific row, if the value does not start with a specific string (in this case a file path), I want to overwrite the contents with values from a different column, same row.

```
for R in df:
     if not R['O_path'].str.startswith('\\correct\\path\\here'):
         R['O_path'] = R['N_path']
     else:
         continue
```

I keep getting "TypeError: string indices must be integers" Clearly I'm doing something wrong, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```py
df.loc[df["O_path"].str.startswith('\\correct\\path\\here'), 'O_path'] = df['N_path']
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
mask = df['O_path'].str.startswith('\\correct\\path\\here')
df.loc[mask, 'O_path'] = df['N_path']
```